# To_NUMBER Function in Oracle

Tags: oracle, type-conversion

I'm studying SQL. I'm having a problem in understanding this. Why TO_NUMBER function accept the value in the first query and return the requested format even though `$` sign is included ? But, in the 2nd query it does not accept the value. Can someone please help me explain how this works?

```
SQL> select to_number('$234.55','$99,999.00') from dual;

TO_NUMBER('$234.55','$99,999.00')
---------------------------------
               234.55

SQL> select to_number('$234.55') from dual;
select to_number('$234.55') from dual
                 *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01722: invalid number
```

Comment: Because the second query doesn't define a format for the number and thus the `$` is not recognized

Comment: Because that's exactly what the second argument is meant for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because "$" is not recognize by to_number without format.
If you want to use "$" the need to write format:
[SQL Fiddle:](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/c583b/59)

```
select to_number('$234.55','$99,999.00') from dual;

select to_number('$234.55','$99,999.00') from dual; 
select to_number('$234.55','$99,999.00') from dual;

select to_number('234.55') from dual; 
select to_number('234.55') from dual;
```